# I'm using AngularFire, How can I retrieve this "email", "uid" data?

Tags: angularjs, object, firebase, angularfire

JS CODE

```
 var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase('https://blinding-inferno-7068.firebaseio.com/');
     var createdUserRef = myFirebaseRef.child('users').child('createdUser');
     $scope.users = $firebaseArray(createdUserRef);
```

HTML CODE

```
        <ul ng-repeat="user in users">
            <li>{{user.uid}}</li>
            <li>{{user.email}}</li>
            <li>{{user}}</li>
        </ul>
```

What I wanted was user.uid and user.email, but those thing didn't come out.
So I checked the user object, and these things came out.

```
{"-Js0q1mWTwK-AZDZyVdc":{"email":"roro7828@gmail.com","uid":"simplelogin:11"},"$id":"simplelogin:11","$priority":null}
```

How can I retrieve the key's value? (I mean email's value and uid's value)

Should I have to retrieve that data by putting code like this?

{{user.-Js0q1mWtwk-AZDZyVdc.email}}

like this ? horrible.

Please help me T_T..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's have a look at your actual data:

```
{
  "users": {
    "createdUser": {
      "simplelogin:11": {
        "-Js0q1mWTwK-AZDZyVdc": {
          "email": "roro7828@gmail.com",
          "uid": "simplelogin:11"
        }
      },
      "simplelogin:12": {
        "-Js0qpcW6jI9Yf3kplCs": {
          "email": "ao7828@gmail.com",
          "uid": "simplelogin:12"
        }
      },
      "simplelogin:13": {
        "-Js0qrEbzYnFOOWtnCbg": {
          "email": "do7828@gmail.com",
          "uid": "simplelogin:13"
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

- You can get such a dump of your data by `new Firebase('https://blinding-inferno-7068.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) { console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val())); }, function(e) { console.error(e); })` or by looking at the Data tab in the dashboard of your application.*

Your `$firebaseArray` contains objects such as this:

```
      "simplelogin:11": {
        "-Js0q1mWTwK-AZDZyVdc": {
          "email": "roro7828@gmail.com",
          "uid": "simplelogin:11"
        }
      },
```

And there is no child `email` under `simplelogin:11`. So that's why you're not seeing that output.

It looks like you accidentally are adding the users with a `$add` operation, which creates the `"-Js0q1mWTwK-AZDZyVdc"` in the sample above. You should instead be using `$save` or just by using the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK:

```
ref.child('users/createdUser').child(user.uid).set(user);
```

Note that it is a bit tricky to explain without seeing the code you use to create those users. So if you **edit** your question to include that code, I'll update my answer.